# How to force parts of regex to match?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex

```
<SharePointWebControls:(\w+).*?fieldname="(.*?)".*?\s*<\/SharePointWebControls:(?:\w+).*?>
```

Notice the two parts of it `(\w+)` and `(?:\w+)`. This regex will match somethign even when these two are different. How can I force it so the matched area has to be the same for these two groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use back-reference to matched groups using `\1`:

```
<SharePointWebControls:(\w+).*?fieldname="(.*?)".*?\s*<\/SharePointWebControls:\1>
```

Here `\1` in later part is actually back-reference to first capturing group which is being captured by `(\w+)`.

[RegEx Demo](http://%3CSharePointWebControls:(%5Cw+).*?fieldname=%22(.*?)%22.*?%5Cs*%3C%5C/SharePointWebControls:%5C1%3E)

Comment: I think it should be `<SharePointWebControls:(\w+).*?fieldname="(.*?)".*?\s*<\/SharePointWebControls:\1>`, the `.*?` near the end is causing problems.

Comment: Yes it is updated. I didn't know your actual input data so kept that part as you had in question.